# Is it possible to create a uniform, vertical border down the centre of a page through multiple tables?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page which repeats the following table multiple times. Currently the two cells equally share half the page. I'd like to place a border between them that runs vertically down the centre of the page. I've tried placing right borders on the cells of the left cell, but it doesn't produce a uniform border because of the spacing between the cells, and the spacing between the separate tables.

Does anyone have any suggestion as to how I could create this uniform border through the centre of the page?

```
<table class="ex2" width="100%">  
<tr>
 <td width=50%><a href="www.test.com"<p style="font-family:verdana">Test Title - Left</p></a></td>
<td width=50%><a href="www.test2.com"><p style="font-family:verdana;color:red">Test Title - Right</p></a></td>   
</tr>    
<tr>    
  <td width=50%><p style="font-family:verdana;color:grey">Test Body - Left</p></td>    
  <td width=50%><p style="font-family:verdana;color:grey">Test Body - Right</p></td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table does not mention what css is on it already. If there is no top/bottom margins on the table then using `border-collapse: collapse` on the table works, see http://jsfiddle.net/GY7CW/3/.

If you have top/bottom margin on the tables, and don't care about IE7 or below, then you can use a wrapping element styled to give you the border via a `:before` pseudo element, see http://jsfiddle.net/GY7CW/2/.

Comment: Beautiful, your second solution is just what I was looking for! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the extra space between the cells you could use:

```
<style type="text/css">
table.ex2{
    border-collapse:    collapse;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a solution that doesn't require me to remove the extra spacing between the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've figured out a simple although potentially simplified solution (if you want to use js/jquery/etc)

There are probably better ways to do what you want (i.e not using tables) but here you go haha

```
<style>

.addborder {
border-right: 1px solid #666;
}

.addspace {
padding-left: 20px;
}

.ex2 { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }

</style>
```

for the css and

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ex2">  
<tr>
 <td class="addborder" width=50%><a href="www.test.com"<p style="font-family:verdana">Test Title - Left</p></a></td>
<td class="addspace" width=50%><a href="www.test2.com"><p style="font-family:verdana;color:red">Test Title - Right</p></a></td>   
</tr>    
<tr>    
  <td class="addborder" width=50%><p style="font-family:verdana;color:grey">Test Body - Left</p></td>    
  <td class="addspace" width=50%><p style="font-family:verdana;color:grey">Test Body - Right</p></td>
</tr></table>
```

for your table html ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Remember not to duplicate IDs; if you need to use the same ID twice use a class instead :)

Comment: And if it is important for you to also have a border for each individual cell, then you can insert a `<div class="yourStyle">Test Title - Left/Right</div>` inside each and set the margins, borders, etc. for that.

Comment: @ChristianVarga fixed :), I was rushing and almost missed my class (pun intended ;) )

Comment: I gave this a shot, and while it does produce a uniform line, it also required me to remove the spacing between my tables to do so. I would've accepted this, but Scott's solution allowed me to achieve my goal without removing the extra spacing.

Comment: you could have simply added 

.ex2 td { padding: 10px;}

to the style to customise your own spacing

however scott's seems to cater closer to your original point anyway if you don't need the extra customisation ;)